# Сравнение элементов массива и ArrayLIst-a

Tags: java, массивы, override

У меня имеется класс **Gene**, который трансформирует 
математическое выражение вида `( x + 3 )` в ,например, массив `array={"+","x","3",null,null,...}` . Логика трансформации `stringEquationToArray(String givenString)` в считывании белых знаков.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Gene {
private String[] gene;

public Gene(String geneString){
    gene= stringEquationToArray(geneString);
}

public String[] getGene() {
    return gene;
}

public static  String[] stringEquationToArray(String givenString) {

    int quantityOfWhiteSpaces = getQuantityOfWhitespaces(givenString);
    int[] whitespaceDestination = getIndexesOfWhiteSpaces(givenString);
    char[] givenCharArray = givenString.toCharArray();
    String[] binTree = new String[15];

    switch (quantityOfWhiteSpaces){
        case 2:
            char[] level0 = Arrays.copyOfRange(givenCharArray, 2, givenCharArray.length - 2);
            binTree[0] = String.copyValueOf(level0);
            break;

        case 4:
            char[] firstEl = Arrays.copyOfRange(givenCharArray, whitespaceDestination[0], whitespaceDestination[1]);
            char[] operand = Arrays.copyOfRange(givenCharArray, whitespaceDestination[1], whitespaceDestination[2]);
            char[] secondEl = Arrays.copyOfRange(givenCharArray, whitespaceDestination[2], whitespaceDestination[3]);
            binTree[0] = String.copyValueOf(operand);
            binTree[1] = String.copyValueOf(firstEl);
            binTree[2] = String.copyValueOf(secondEl);
            break;
    }
    return binTree;
}

/**
 * returns indexes of whitespaces.
 */
private static int[] getIndexesOfWhiteSpaces(String givenString) {
    char[] givenCharArray = givenString.toCharArray();
    int[] whiteSpacePlace = new int[46];
    int indexOfWhitespaces = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < givenCharArray.length; i++) {

        if (Character.isWhitespace(givenCharArray[i]) == true) {
            whiteSpacePlace[indexOfWhitespaces] = i;
            indexOfWhitespaces++;
        }
    }
    return whiteSpacePlace;
}

/**
 * returns quantity of white spaces.
 */
private  static int getQuantityOfWhitespaces(String givenString) {
    char[] givenCharArray = givenString.toCharArray();
    int indexOfWhitespaces = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < givenCharArray.length; i++) {

        if (Character.isWhitespace(givenCharArray[i])) {
            indexOfWhitespaces++;
        }
    }
    return indexOfWhitespaces;
}
```

}

Когда я тестирую **Gene** , я хочу проверить приналежность рандомного елемента массива `array` к множеству `set`, у меня постоянно выкидывает `false` там, где должно быть `true`.

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class Test {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> set = new ArrayList<>();
    set.add("x");
    set.add("x^2");


    String stringArray = "( x - 34 )";

    Gene gene = new Gene(stringArray);
    gene.getGene();


    if(set.contains(gene.getGene()[1])){
        System.out.println("YES");
    }else{
        System.out.println("NO");
      }
   }
}
```

Я почти уверен что надо переопределить метод `contains`, но никак у меня не выходит.

Comment: Сложно понять, что должно находиться в `gene` массиве. Можно добавить в вопросс его вместимость в данном случае?

Comment: вы как-то очень сложно все делаете, и скорее всего с ошибками (результаты содержат лишние пробелы). Чтобы порезать строку на подстроки по разделителю, используйте [`String.split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)).

Comment: в `Gene` находится бинарное дерево в виде массива стрингов.

Comment: @zRrr согласен, но в данном случае и тот метод работает, у меня проблема в другом. Если выписать `gene.getGene()` то там будет массив(- , х ,34) . Но при `set.contains(gene.getGene()[1] получается `false`. Что не так?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас класс `Gene` генерирует строки с пробелом спереди и сравнивает `" x"` c `"x"`

```
ArrayList<String> set = new ArrayList<>();
set.add("x");
set.add("x^2");


String stringArray = "( x - 34 )";

Gene gene = new Gene(stringArray);
String s = gene.getGene();


if(set.contains(gene.getGene()[1])){ 

//s[1] = " x" 
//set.contains("x") == true
//set.contains(" x") == false.   

System.out.println("YES");
}else{
    System.out.println("NO");
  }
}
```